# Modelling Tennis Torunament with EF6

Tags: database, entity-framework-6, entity-relationship

I want to generate a tennis tournament and i thought about this solution:

```
public class Torneo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int NrGiocatori { get; set; }
    public virtual Provincia Provincia { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Girone> Gironi { get; set; }
    public virtual List<TurnoTabellone> TurniTabellone { get; set; }
}

public class Girone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TorneoId { get; set; }
    public string NomeGirone { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PartitaGirone> PartiteGirone { get; set; }
}

public class PartitaGirone : Partita
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GironeId { get; set; }

}

public class TurnoTabellone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TorneoId { get; set; }
    public Turno Turno { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PartitaTabellone> PartiteTabellone { get; set; }
}

public class PartitaTabellone : Partita
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TurnoTabelloneId { get; set; }
}

public class Partita
{
    public int IdGiocatore1 { get; set; }
    public int IdGIocaotre2 { get; set; }
    public int GameGiocatore1 { get; set; }
    public int GameGiocatore2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataIncontro { get; set; }
    public int OraIncontro { get; set; }
}
```

Torneo = Tournament

Girone = Round Robin

PartitaGirone = Round Robin Match

TurnoTabellone = BoardRound, for example all Quarter of final/Semifinal/Final...

PartitaTabellone = Board Match

Partita = Match

Provincia = Province

This is the ER model:

[image]

What dumfounded me is the duplication of the matches fields in PARTITAGIRONE and PARTITATABELLONE.
On the other hand i can't use just one table for "match" because of different relationships between GIRONE and TURNOTABELLONE.

Any tip?
I also avoid to add players in the entities because i still don't know where to put them.

UPDATE 1:

And what if i use a single table for match even if i have some null foreign Keys in base of what entity i'm populating?

I fill some data to test with LinqPad:

[image]

[image]

For Girone (Round Robin) i will have TurnoTabelloneId (Round Board Id) null, viceversa if i fill TurnoTabelloneId and if i don't fill anything i will have a third case that rapresents a single match not bound with tournament.

In the first step i didn't want to leave foreign Keys blank, but, i thought about it and now it doesn't seem to me a bad idea.

The new rapresentation of the ER is:

[image]